# SyntaxError: Invalid character '\ud835'

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, safari, ethers.js

SyntaxError: Invalid character '\ud835'

When running a web application (built with Typescript + Webpack) inside Safari I am facing the error above (not faced in other browsers).

From searching all node_modules, ethers.js contains:

const EtherSymbol = "\u039e"; // "\uD835\uDF63";\n//#

Answer (score 1):

The solution in this specific scenario was to add the terser plugin within webpack 5.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/

```
const isModern = false;
const customTerserOptions = { ... } // from this url - https://github.com/terser/terser/issues/729

module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
            terserOptions: customTerserOptions
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case this code did the trick

```js
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

const webpackConfig = {
  ...
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      terserOptions: {
        safari10: true
      }
    })],
  }
  ...
}

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```